# How do I link my HTML button to a JS onclick

Tags: javascript, html, linker

I do not know the correct syntax for linking a *HTML* button to a *JS* onclick

P.S I have checked google and DevDocs for answers and there were none

Comment: Are you looking for this? - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: It's very hard for me to believe you did not find any documentation or the simple example if you search for: "javascript onclick example"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an EventListener linked to your html element in your JavaScript file.

html

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

js

```
const testButton = document.querySelector('.test');
testButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Code you want to execute 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML button has an attribute called onClick. You can call your JS function inside onClick.

ex:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onClick="disp()">Display</button>
  <div id="text"></div>
  <script>
    function disp(){
      document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = 'Hello world';
    }
  </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is bad practice to declare `js` events in html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Link an EventListener to your html element in your Js file.
**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**Js**

```
const testButton = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
testButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Code you want to execute 
});
```

Use onClick Attribute to call your Js function.
**HTML**

```
<button onClick="myFunc()">Display</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**Js**

```
function myFunc () {
      document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = "Hello world";
    }
```

I hope I was helpful.